# How to use a remote docker server from jenkins?

Tags: docker, jenkins, server, distance, using

I got 2 servers, 1 Linux 2 AMI with Jenkins running and one RHEL with Docker running.

I would like to configure Jenkins in order to build and deploy an application on the Docker server. If I clone my repository on the Docker server, i'm running docker-compose build then docker-compose up and everything is working fine.

I find some documentation about using a remote docker server with jenkins but it doesn't work. Docker API is already open.

Comment: When you say “Docker API is open”...what did you do exactly?  Anyone who can access the Docker API has unrestricted root access over the host, and systems _have_ gotten compromised this way.

Comment: I added tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 on the line ExecStart from docker.service file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you can connect to a remote Docker Daemon by enabling the [Remote API over TCP](https://success.docker.com/article/how-do-i-enable-the-remote-api-for-dockerd) and using the docker client by setting the `DOCKER_HOST` [environment variable](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#environment-variables). I would also suggest you configure [encryption and authentication](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https) to have an additional layer of security and if you can restrict it to be only accessible from your Jenkins Slaves.

But as stated on the comment by David Maze, I don't think this is the best approach for deployment of containers as it carries some security risks that can compromise your servers.

I would suggest that if you are planning on running production workloads and you need a full pipeline for managing the lifecycle of your applications running on containers, you research [Docker Swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/) or [Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io) as they are better alternatives suited for achieving this.

Comment: It's just for testing, no real production application is deployed. I will check docker swarm but is it not a waste ? Because i got only 1 docker.

Comment: you can create a swarm network containing a single(manager) node